# Sitefinity: How can you update the revision of a document programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, sitefinity

In Sitefinity, almost everything is able to be revisioned. In the backend interface at a page for a content item you can click on Revision History and see revisions.

[image]

We're in a situation where we're manually uploading documents in to the Documents & Files library through a custom form. We're able to do this using the Content Lifecycle which has pretty good documentation: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/gettingstarted/developers-guide/sitefinity-essentials/modules/content-lifecycle .

What doesn't have any documentation is how to modify a document so that it updates the revision of that document programmatically, not replace it. Right now, we're only able to replace it and the revision history stays empty.

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot keep the previous version of the document in Sitefinity. 
The revision history for the documents keeps track for the metadata only, e.g. Title, Author, etc. 
If you replace the file, there is no way to revert it back through the Revision History.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this in the 7+ versions.

Comment: If that's true that's a good point that I did not realize. (I am indeed using 7+).

Comment: Yeah, better test thoroughly first so you don't end up with lost documents. After that you might want to mark this issue as completed.